# IIS. How rewrite/redirect from url https://site1.com/Repo/* to https://site2.com/Repo/*?

Tags: iis

Tell me please how i can make rewrite/redirect on IIS from url https://site1.com/Repo/* to https://site2.com/Repo/* ?

I want that for example https://site1.com/Repo/324234234234234 redirect to https://site2.com/Repo/324234234234234

Thank you advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule, the pattern is using a regular expression, to check if {HTTP_HOST} is equal to `site1.com`, the {R:1} in the action means whatever is in the URL behind the domain name itself.

```
<rule name="test1">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site1.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://site2.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```